# Influencing class variables with functions that are method's variables

Tags: python, function, oop, variables

Say I have a class with a method that takes a function as an argument. Is there any way to make this function change inclass variables?

```
def f():
    # something here to change MyClass.var

class MyClass:
    def __init__():
        self.var = 1

    def method(self, func):
        #does something
        func()

obj = MyClass()
obj.method(f)
print(obj.var)
```

Comment: Pass `self` to `func`.

Comment: Trying to call obj.method(f) should throw an error saying `expected 1 arguments, found 2` because if you say `obj.<method>` python expects the corresponding method definition to have a `self` argument

Comment: corrected that, thanks

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply pass the internal reference of your class - `self` - into the function:

```
>>> class Class:
        def __init__(self):
            self.var = 1

        def method(self, func):
            func(self)

>>> def func(inst):
        inst.var = 0


>>> cls = Class()
>>> cls.var
1
>>> cls.method(func)
>>> cls.var
0
>>>
```

On a related side note, I'd argue that it'd be cleaner and clearer to actually make your function a method of your class:

```
>>> from types import MethodType
>>> 
>>> def func(self):
        self.var = 0


>>> class Class:
        def __init__(self):
            self.var = 1


>>> cls = Class()
>>> cls.var
1
>>> cls.func = MethodType(func, cls)
>>> cls.func()
>>> cls.var
0
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def f(obj):
    obj.var = 2

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1

    def method(self, func):
        # does something
        func(self)

obj = MyClass()
obj.method(f)
print(obj.var)  # --> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the function `f` is defined outside the scope of the class, it can not access the class variable. However you can pass the class variable as an argument to f, and in that case it will be able to do any operation on it.

```
def f(x):
    return x**2  # just for the demonstration. Will square the existing value\\
  # of the class variable


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 2

    def method(self, func):
        #does something
        self.var = func(self.var)

obj = MyClass()
obj.method(f)
print(obj.var)   
>>> 4
```